# Is there a triangle which makes dense set of angles?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, real-numbers, tiling

We start from a predefined triangle in a plane,
at first we have 3 angles of the triangle in set $A$.
in each level we add angles of triangles created by drawing medians of each triangle created from the latter level to $A$.

What can we say about $A$?

Is there a specific triangle which lead us to a dense set of angles between 0 and $\pi$ through this procedure?

If no ,does there exist another simple alternative to this procedure(medians) like another defined concurance lines in triangles, which achieves our goal?

Note: 
There are at least two possible interpretations of the allowed operations.

- **3 x 2 x 1/2** - In each step, pick a triangle $T$ from previous step. Split $T$ into $2$ pieces by cutting $T$ along one of the $3$ medians. You are leave with $6$ smaller triangles whose area is one-half of that of $T$.
- **6 x 1/6** - In each step, pick a triangle $T$ from previous step. Split $T$
  in $6$ pieces by cutting $T$ along all $3$ medians. You are leave with $6$ smaller triangles whose area is one-sixth of that of $T$.

**Update**:
Problem is solved under interpretation **3 x 2 x 1/2** by *achille hui* below.
For  **6 x 1/6** interpretation the problem is reanounced in Mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/301496/revisions) and answered there through a [nice article](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fc-2017-06).

Comment: Note that this process (and anything like it) will only ever produce countably many angles ...

Comment: At each step, the set of angles you can get is finite. This means your final $A$ is a countable union of finite sets and hence countable. It is impossible for it to cover $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: I haven't proved it, but it seems unlikely you will get new angles close to $\pi$.  I don't know the greatest you can get, but it doesn't look much more than $\frac \pi 2$.  It might be better to ask if the angles are dense in $(0,\frac \pi 2)$  It may also be hard to get angles close to $0$.

Comment: @ross millikan I think if $A$ be dense on a closed subset of $(0,\pi)$ thet it will be dense on whole of it.

Comment: @ross millikan I don't know if there is a measure for density ,if what you say be true the we can say $A$ is less dense close to $\pi$.

Comment: I am not aware of a formal one.  A set is either dense or it is not.  But you can notice that you rarely generate angles close to $\pi$ even if there are enough of them to be dense.  You could ask what fraction of the first $n$ angles you generate are in various intervals and discover that the intervals near the ends get populated more slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two possible interpretations of the allowed operations.

- **3 x 2 x 1/2** - In each step, pick a triangle $T$ from previous step. Split $T$ into $2$ pieces by cutting $T$ along one of the $3$ medians. You are leave with $6$ smaller triangles whose area is one-half of that of $T$.
- **6 x 1/6** - In each step, pick a triangle $T$ from previous step. Split $T$
  in $6$ pieces by cutting $T$ along all $3$ medians. You are leave with $6$ smaller triangles whose area is one-sixth of that of $T$.

I'm going to show under interpretation (**3 x 2 x 1/2**),  $A$ is dense in $(0,\pi)$.

---

For any two points $P,Q$, let

- $\verb/mid/(P,Q)$ be the mid-point of $P$ and $Q$.
- $\verb/seg/(P,Q)$ be the line segment joining $P$ (inclusive) and $Q$ (exclusive)

Start from any predefined triangle $\triangle BCD$ and angle $\alpha \in (0,\pi)$,

Construct a sequence of triangles $\triangle B_pCD$ by setting 
$$B_p = \begin{cases} B, & p = 0\\
\verb/mid/(B_{p-1},D) & p > 0\end{cases}$$ 
Since $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty} \angle B_pCD \to 0$, we can pick a $p$ with $\angle B_pCD < \min(\alpha,\pi-\alpha)$. Call this $B_p$ as $E$.

Construct another sequence of triangles $\triangle E_qCD$ by setting
$$E_q = \begin{cases} E, & q = 0\\
\verb/mid/(E_{q-1},C), & q > 0\end{cases}$$
Since $\lim\limits_{q\to\infty} \angle CDE_q = 0$, we can pick a $q$ with $\angle CDE_q < \min(\alpha,\pi-\alpha)$. Call this $E_q$ as $F$.

In $\triangle FCD$, since both angles $\angle FCD, \angle CDF < \min(\alpha,\pi-\alpha)$, there is a point $G \in \verb/seg/(C,D)$ with $\angle FGD = \alpha$. Construct
yet another sequence of triangles $\triangle FC_rD_r$ by setting

$$(C_r, D_r) = \begin{cases}
(C_0,D_0), & r = 0\\
(C_{r-1},M_{r-1}), & r > 0, G \in \verb/seg/(C_{r-1},M_{r-1})\\
(M_{r-1},D_{r-1}), & r > 0, G \in \verb/seg/(M_{r-1},D_{r-1})
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ where }\quad 
M_{r-1} = \verb/mid/(C_{r-1},D_{r-1})
$$
In each step, $\verb/seg/(C_r,D_r)$ is a segment containing $G$. The whole
process is essentially a procedure which locates $G$ by bisection of line segment
containing it.

All the triangles constructed so far are created by drawing medians of some existing triangles.
This implies $\angle FC_rD_r \in A$. As $r$ increases, both $C_r$ and $D_r$ converges to $G$. Furthermore,
$\angle FC_rD_r$ converges to $\alpha$ from below. 
This means $\alpha$ belongs to closure of $A$.

Since $\alpha$ can be any number from $(0,\pi)$, we can conclude
under interpretation (**3 x 2 x 1/2**), $A$ is dense over $(0,\pi)$.
I have no idea what happens under interpretation (**6 x 1/6**).

Comment: @achile hui If we just consider triangles which are made does not contain anothers in each step(for example we start with a triangle ,in second step we have just 6, third 36 and so on...) Then would this be true? : 
All the triangles constructed so far are created by drawing medians of some existing triangles.  
This implies $\angle FC_rD_r \in A$. As $r$ increases, both $C_r$ and $D_r$ converges to $G$

Comment: @SolarGalaxy Do you mean in each step, you split and only allow to split a triangle in previous step into $6$ smaller triangles. At the end of $n$-step, you have $6^n$ triangles. If that is the case, it is completely different from my understanding of your question. I don't what happens in that case.

Comment: good proof but actually I meant $6×(1/6)$ from beginning which leads to smaller and smaller pieces each step and whole of them tile the triangle at the inception. In order to have and respect your proof I won't edit the primary question format. Furthermore It may help audiences finding whole solution.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. see the update and reannouncement of the problem in overflow and the nice article answered there.